# How to get IE 11 to apply CSS change for pseudo element, that Chrome/FF apply fine?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-awesome

[This page](https://www.spirent.com/Assets/CS/CS_AMR-GPS-interference-Issues) has a form with two checkboxes that have custom CSS styling.

If you look at the page in Chrome/Firefox and check either box (not the recaptcha, just the two checkboxes above), the black checkmark shows up.  But if you look at the page in IE 11 and check either box, the checkmark does NOT show.  The tick is registered, but the font-awesome checkmark doesn't appear.

When the checkbox first appears on the page, this is the default CSS.  The checkmark is there, it's just colored white so you can't see it:

```
input + label:before {
    content: "\f00c";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Then when you tick the checkbox, this CSS should take over (and does on Chrome/FF, but not IE):

```
input:checked + label:before {
    content: "\f00c";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Any ideas how to make IE respect the check action to apply that 2nd CSS above (really just the part changing color from white to black)?

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47529361/how-to-design-a-radio-button-which-looks-the-sam-in-firefox-chrome-and-ie11/47529852#47529852

Comment: FYI Ghostery is blocking that form entirely

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-ms-check

Comment: I will check into these, thx.  Also, curious why when you inspect in IE, all the custom styling is crossed out. Even if I add `input[type=checkbox]::-ms-check { color: red; }` as a test, it gets crossed out immediately and NOT applied.